# STLport c_str() incorrect return value

Tags: c++, stl, stlport

I have encountered a problem with ***stlport*** STL implementation. I use it for Android, though platform probably not relevant here.
I’m using a third-party shared library, which tries to open certain file. That file path is passed to function as `std::string`, and then it comes to library inline function:

```
inline bool ReadProtoFromTextFile(const string& filename, Message* proto) {
  return ReadProtoFromTextFile(filename.c_str(), proto);
}
```

and then that C string is used as an argument to `open()` function. The problem is that with ***stlport***, `ReadProtoFromTextFile` function receives non-valid C string, thus failing to open file. That non-valid C string is deterministic, it is always this sequence of characters:

> p!&\xffffffe8.

When I try to call c_str() from my code it is always valid. 
I have tried to look into problematic string with LLDB and got this error:
error: The expression could not be prepared to run in the target

Still, it is possible to check internal structure of that string and problematic string sequence is present there in `_M_buffers._M_end_of_storage` field. Correct sequence is also there in `_M_buffers._M_start_of_storage`.

When I have switched to ***gnustl*** implementation, the problem was gone. And LLDB showed .c_str() without any problems. For me, it looks like some inlining problem, but what could it be? ***stlport_shared*** is recommended implementation by Google, after all.

Comment: Is the life-time of the `std::string` valid? Is it alive by the end of the function?

Comment: Yes, it is definitely alive. And the same code works flawlessly with gnustl.